# FluentFTP. Как вывести содержимое папки ftp сервера. Мне нужно просмотреть все файлы с расширениями оттуда

Tags: c#, winforms, ftp

Я уже задавал подобный вопрос, но там ответ был на фтпвебреквест, который рекомендуется не использовать, и как я понял альтернатива ему - FluentFTP. И я толком ничего не нашел по флуенту, мб плохо искал. Страницу гитхаба разве что и все.

Comment: Не надо говорить, что не рекомендуется - не значит, что нельзя. Там тоже такое себе решение...

Comment: Опубликуйте ответ, как ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
client.SetWorkingDirectory("/public_html/"); //сюда пишется директория 
foreach (FtpListItem item in client.GetListing())
{
    if (item.Type == FtpFileSystemObjectType.File)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(item.Name); //внос в листбокс
    }
}
```